# Naming a method `get` causes error

Tags: dart, angular-dart

See this simple class and method:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@Injectable()
class ApiClient {

  final Client _http;
  static final _headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
  static final _encodedHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };

  ApiClient(this._http);

  Future<T> get<T>(String url, T f(dynamic e)) async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.get(url);
      var data = JSON.decode(response.body);
      print(data);
      if(data == null)return null;
      final ts = f(data);
      return ts;
    } catch (e) {
      _handleError(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

It causes this error:

> Unexpected token 'Future'.
>
> Future get(String url, T f(dynamic e)) async {
>
> ^^^^^^

and when I rename the method say get1 the error goes away. Is this normal? I have other classes with method named get and works just fine. Am I missing something here?

[See the issue on github](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32347)

**UPDATE:**

It doesn't seem to me to be an identifier issue. Cause I can name a method `get` and there wouldn't be any error. Also, there is some built-in classes which have methods named `get` (e.g. `Client` class). It seems naming a generic-method to `get` causes the error: `get<T>()`. I agree with [Vyacheslav Egorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662844/vyacheslav-egorov) - as said in comment, and I think this is a parser bug.

Answer (score 6):

`get` is a built-in identifier to define a getter and should not be used as identifier

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour[image]

Comment: It should not cause an error. Grammar permits you to have a method called `get`, you just can't have a class called `get`. This looks like a bug to me in the parser.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense, while there are built-in classes have method named `get` (and I have some too). It seems just generic-`get` is not allowed. See the update please.